# Cannot decode UTF-8 buffer to desired data structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8

Before marking this question as a duplicate , I must state that I am aware of the other posts that transform a buffer in an array of buffers (I have been trying virtually every  thread's comments on this , but is not what Im looking for).

I am using Node's child process to run a python script .The script returns a list in the form of :

```
[["a","21","67"],["b","22","69"]]
```

As per the Node child process docs , the result is UTF8 encoded. The problem is that whenever I try with textDecoder :

```
const response=new TextDecoder(data).decode(data);
```

or with regex:

```
var response = data.toString()
var ressult= a.match(/\d+/g);
```

None of them (and many variations of them that I have tried) work as I expect. Ultimately , I just want to get a javascript array ( `[["a","21","67"],["b","22","69"]]` ) so that I can perform functions on it(or , in other words, the list returned from the python script itself).Thank you !

Edit:
This is my child process:

```
 const { spawn } = require('child_process');

            const pyProg= spawn(`${srcDirectory}/venv/Scripts/python.exe`,[`${srcDirectory}/optimization/optimizationFunction.py`]);

            pyProg.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
                console.log(data.toString())
            });
```

And this is what is logged by `data.toString()`:

```
[['r1', '1e45200a-f990-4fda-a76b-b00fa05d9f53', 200.0], ['r2', '1e45200a-f990-4fda-a76b-b00fa05d9f53', 199.9999999999999], ['r1', '1ea3890a-f990-4fda-a76b-b00fa05d9f53', 0.0], ['r2', '1ea3890a-f990-4fda-a76b-b00fa05d9f53', 0.0]]
```

This is what console.log(data) logs:

```
<Buffer 53 65 74 20 70 61 72 61 6d 65 74 65 72 20 55 73 65 72 6e 61 6d 65 0d 0a>
<Buffer 41 63 61 64 65 6d 69 63 20 6c 69 63 65 6e 73 65 20 2d 20 66 6f 72 20 6e 6f 6e 2d 63 6f 6d 6d 65 72 63 69 61 6c 20 75 73 65 20 6f 6e 6c 79 20 2d 20 65 ... 19 more bytes>
<Buffer 47 75 72 6f 62 69 20 4f 70 74 69 6d 69 7a 65 72 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 20 39 2e 35 2e 30 20 62 75 69 6c 64 20 76 39 2e 35 2e 30 72 63 35 20 28 77 69 ... 6 more bytes>
<Buffer 54 68 72 65 61 64 20 63 6f 75 6e 74 3a 20 34 20 70 68 79 73 69 63 61 6c 20 63 6f 72 65 73 2c 20 38 20 6c 6f 67 69 63 61 6c 20 70 72 6f 63 65 73 73 6f ... 334 more bytes>
<Buffer 50 72 65 73 6f 6c 76 65 20 72 65 6d 6f 76 65 64 20 31 33 20 72 6f 77 73 20 61 6e 64 20 34 20 63 6f 6c 75 6d 6e 73 0d 0a>
<Buffer 50 72 65 73 6f 6c 76 65 20 74 69 6d 65 3a 20 30 2e 30 30 73 0d 0a 50 72 65 73 6f 6c 76 65 64 3a 20 36 20 72 6f 77 73 2c 20 37 20 63 6f 6c 75 6d 6e 73 ... 67 more bytes>
<Buffer 46 6f 75 6e 64 20 68 65 75 72 69 73 74 69 63 20 73 6f 6c 75 74 69 6f 6e 3a 20 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 69 76 65 20 32 32 32 30 30 2e 30 30 30 30 30 30 0d 0a>     
<Buffer 46 6f 75 6e 64 20 68 65 75 72 69 73 74 69 63 20 73 6f 6c 75 74 69 6f 6e 3a 20 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 69 76 65 20 32 31 32 30 30 2e 30 30 30 30 30 30 0d 0a ... 227 more bytes>
<Buffer 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 63 75 74 6f 66 66 20 20 20 20 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 32 31 32 30 30 2e 30 30 30 30 20 32 31 32 ... 761 more bytes>
<Buffer 47 75 72 6f 62 69 20 4f 70 74 69 6d 69 7a 65 72 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 20 39 2e 35 2e 30 20 62 75 69 6c 64 20 76 39 2e 35 2e 30 72 63 35 20 28 77 69 ... 250 more bytes>
<Buffer 20 20 4d 61 74 72 69 78 20 72 61 6e 67 65 20 20 20 20 20 5b 31 65 2b 30 30 2c 20 39 65 2b 30 33 5d 0d 0a 20 20 4f 62 6a 65 63 74 69 76 65 20 72 61 6e ... 90 more bytes>
<Buffer 50 72 65 73 6f 6c 76 65 20 72 65 6d 6f 76 65 64 20 31 33 20 72 6f 77 73 20 61 6e 64 20 34 20 63 6f 6c 75 6d 6e 73 0d 0a 50 72 65 73 6f 6c 76 65 20 74 ... 55 more bytes>
<Buffer 56 61 72 69 61 62 6c 65 20 74 79 70 65 73 3a 20 35 20 63 6f 6e 74 69 6e 75 6f 75 73 2c 20 32 20 69 6e 74 65 67 65 72 20 28 32 20 62 69 6e 61 72 79 29 ... 2 more bytes>
```

Additionally, this is what typeof data.toString() returns :

```
string
string
string
string
string
string
string
string
string
string
string
```

Comment: "*As per the Node child process docs , the result is UTF8 encoded.*" - no it isn't. The encoding depends on your Python script - although for the output you've shown, it doesn't matter as it's all ASCII characters. Node does either pass you the raw buffers, or it *de*codes them using UTF-8 by default and does pass you strings, depending on how you use the child process object. Which one is it? Please [edit] your question to include the code you are using to create the child process and receive data, and include what `console.log(data)` prints. Only then we can help you.

Comment: @Bergi I have just updated it , hope it is more clear now

Comment: That buffer data contains a lot of text (output of Gurobi Optimizer) none of which looks like the JSON list you expect

Comment: @Bergi How would you go around this ? I simply want to access the output of the optimization in node..

Comment: Is there some flag that can turn off any output (preamble text etc) but the solution?

Comment: An alternative might be writing the solution to a file using a standardised format and reading that, e.g. using https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-gurobi-solution

Comment: @Bergi I'm afraid no. I always get details about the optimization process ...

Comment: @Bergi What is interesting for me is that when I execute the above outlined code , I get all these strings (as stated in the post).But when I do this :`var dataSet=[]
            pyProg.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
                dataSet.push(data)
            });
            pyProg.on('close', (code) => {
                console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
                console.log(dataSet.join(""))
                console.log(typeof dataSet)
            });`, dataSet is one string , and the gurobi optimization analytics are still being shown.

Comment: @Bergi I think I found a workaround for this: write the solution to a csv/excel file and then parse its contents to access the solution. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I got you right here, but it sounds like the output from Python is already present when you access it. However, when you got your data it's a string first that needs to be parsed to a JavaScript Array.

Try

```
let myArray = JSON.parse(result);
```

to see, if the array is afterwards what you expected.

Comment: Well yes it is type string , but it is not one (after I do `data.toString()`) , there are multiple. I have tried `JSON.parse()` also but it doesnt work ....

Comment: Could you please add an example of the "wrong" output that you are getting after trying to decode it? It's hard to imagine what is going wrong without knowing, what your results are.

Comment: With JSON.parse() it throws an error from the start. But with other methods like ArrayBuffer or the ones I have mentioned give many arrays like `Buffer [ 4c 65 72...]`